# React: prop is not passed to child component on parent re-render

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in my parent component:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <LaunchSidebar game={this.state.game} />
            {!this.state.isLaunchingGame && <Loader/>}
            <div ref="game-container" id="game-container"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And in `LaunchSidebar`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ game: { ...nextProps.game }});
}
```

I set up breakpoints and see that each time `render` in parent is called, after that `componentWillReceiveProps` is called. However, while `this.state.game` has properties, `nextProps.game` is an empty object.

How come it may be?

I use React 16.2

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the game as state in the LaunchSidebar component, I'd recommend you swap the componentWillReceiveProps method with componentDidUpdate.

For example:

```
componentDidMount(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.game !== this.props.game) {
        this.updateGame(this.props.game);
    }
}

updateGame = (game) => {
    this.setState({ game });
}
```

Note, that in order to update the state inside the componentDidMount lifecycle method, you should wrap it in a conditional, else it will be stuck in a loop.

I would consider keeping it simple and update game in the parent component and use it as a prop in the child component, since the state being updated in the parent component will cause a re-render and the game prop in the child component will also be updated.